# How to resolve instance of IHubContext<T> in my MVC5 controller with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, unity-container

I need to send a `SignalR` message from within a controller action. The application is written in MVC5 and .net framework 4.6.1, and I use Unity for Dependency Injection.

How can I register the `IHubContext<T>` implementations so that they can be successfully resolved in the controller's constructor injection?

All articles I have read about `SignalR` and Unity are about how to inject services to the Hubs but this is not what I need. I need to inject SignalR services (`IHubContext<T>`) to my controller but I always get resolve errors.

I also **don't** want to register the Hubs. I want to register the context.

Comment: Do you get an answer to this?